# String with comma-separated values and newlines: split values and create arrays for each newline

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0, ruby-2.1

I have a string like this (from a form submission):

```
"apple, banana\r\ncherries\r\n\r\ngrapes, blue berries \r\n\r\n \r\norange"
```

How do I detect values AND create an array for each line that has text? Like this:

```
[
  ["apple", "banana"],
  ["cherries"],
  ["grapes", "blue berries"],
  ["orange"]
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s = "apple, banana\r\ncherries\r\n\r\ngrapes, blue berries \r\n\r\n \r\norange"
s.each_line.reject { |l| l =~ /^\s+$/ }.map { |l| l.strip.split(', ') }
```

There is definitely something shorter

Comment: The data should be treated like CSV data. Arbitrarily splitting on commas works in this case but would  fail if there was an embedded comma.

Answer (score 4):

```
require "csv"

str = "apple, banana\r\ncherries\r\n\r\ngrapes, blue berries \r\n\r\n \r\norange"

rows = CSV.parse(str, skip_blanks: true)
rows = rows.map{|row| row.map(&:strip)} # remove leading and trailing whitespace
rows.delete([""]) 

p rows # => [["apple", "banana"], ["cherries"], ["grapes", "blue berries"], ["orange"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

More of the same:

```
s.each_line.map { |l| l.strip.split(', ') }.reject(&:empty?)
```

Ruby is fun stuff!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
a = "apple, banana\r\ncherries\r\n\r\ngrapes, blue berries \r\n\r\n \r\norange"
a.gsub("\r", "").each_line.map{|d| d.strip.split(",")}.reject(&:empty?)
```

...and you can definitely refactor this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
s = "apple, banana\r\ncherries\r\n\r\ngrapes, blue berries \r\n\r\n \r\norange"

result = s.split(/[\r\n]+/).map do |match|
  next unless match =~ /\w/
  match.strip.split(/,\s?/)
end

result.compact # => [["apple", "banana"], ["cherries"], ["grapes", "blue berries"], ["orange"]]
```

If terse is better:

```
s.split(/[\r\n]+/).map { |m| next unless m =~ /\w/; m.strip.split(/,\s?/) }.compact
```